# Add progress bar to bottom of screen programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

**Introduction**

Hi,
what I basically want to do is to add a view at the bottom of my layout.

**Detailed information**

I have a scroll view with 5 results. Those 5 results are generated through a for-loop and displayed in an async task. The first time I run the app a progress bar (loading circle from now on) appears and signals the user that he has to wait. The progress bar is done via XML. 
The rest of the layout is done programmatically. When the user now scrolls to the end of the display another 5 results are loaded. What I want to now is to signal it to the user by displaying a loading circle again.

Previous I used `linearlayout.removeView(progressBar)` to remove the progress bar but now I also want to add a loading circle when the rest of the results are being displayed.

**Approach**

What I tried to use was to not use `linearlayout.removeView(progressBar)` but to use `progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE/View.VISIBLE)` instead depending on if I want to make it visible or not

**Problem encountering**

The problem I have now is, that the loading circle is always displayed at the top of the android app, but I want it to be shown at the bottom of my results so the user actually sees the progressBar.

**What I want to achieve**

Basically just that the progressBar is at the bottom of the screen and not at the top of it. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Could you position the ProgressBar Relative to the bottom of the screen and just toggle it's visibility as and when needed?

Comment: No, but that gave me an idea. What about if I get the height of the screen resolution and sen set the padding from top to the height of the screen resolution minus 48dp? This could work, right?

Comment: Update: Ok, this won't work since it will just set the padding from top of the results to the height. So it's still at top

Comment: are the async task results and the progress indicator child of the same parent in your design ? If yes then try using Relative Layout with loader anchored with your async result container and using setVisibility funtion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can try out is `linearlayout.removeView(progressBar)` when the results are done loading.. then when you scroll down.. you again add this `progressBar` to the `linearlayout` i.e., `linearlayout.addView(progressBar);`.

That'll do it for you..

Edit:

Doing something like this would not throw any exception:

```
View v = linearlayout.getChildAt(linearlayout.getChildCount()-1);
if(v != progressBar)
     linearlayout.addView(progressBar);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm getting an `IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call remove View() on the child's parent first.`

I guess this problem occurs, because when the user scrolls to the end multiple times before the AsyncTask is finished it wants to add the progressBar multiple times, which won't work. But thanks for your approach. Any other solutions?

Comment: yup.. that could be a problem.. 

What you can do is.. when you scroll down you can check whether the progressBar is already there or not. You can do this by 



`View v = linearLayout.getChildAt(linearlayout.getChildCount()-1);

if(v!=progressBar) 

    //add progressBar`

Comment: Awesome, that worked. I accepted your answer. But you should edit it and put this comment into the answer too so other people find the solution more easier